# Website completely messes up when logging out

Tags: php, css, html

Alright so the website is completely perfect when I am logged into the WP-ADMIN page but if I log out of there, the website is completely messed up. All the formatting is broken and everything looks weird.

You can see it for yourself here: https://www.CounterBoosting.com
This is how it looks when logged in: https://s18.postimg.io/k4pviuh0n/after.png

One thing to note is that /wp-admin suddenly leads to Page not found 404 and that I can only login using /wp-login.php
Does anyone know what the problem is behind all of this? This happened all of a sudden, without any update to wordpress.
Thank you

Comment: My JS Console is full of 404 failed to load CSS errors, the only stylesheets loading are the ones loaded with caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the browser's console, you can see that several stylesheets are not loading. Also, there's this error:

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.counterboosting.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/M9BPLCjIz8wryU3NK9EvLqnMSQUA.css".

It appears that you have a plugin installed that does caching/script minification, and something is not configured correctly there. The plugin is probably configured to NOT serve cached pages to logged in users, so that's why it looks fine when you're in the admin area. Disable the caching/script minification plugin, and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: I have disabled the caching plugin and it fixed it. Thank you very much

Comment: You got it! Please hit the accept button if this fixed the issue, and welcome to WP StackExchange.

Comment: thank you, i have hit the accept button, thanks again :)